# Generate configs based on jinja2 template on specific hosts in Ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-inventory

My host file:

```
all:
  children:
    LAS:
      children:
        routers:
         hosts:
           1.1.1.1:
           2.2.2.2:
        switchs:
         hosts:
           3.3.3.3:
           4.4.4.4:
    LAS2:
      children:
        routers:
         hosts:
           5.5.5.5:
           6.6.6.6:
        switches:
         hosts:
           7.7.7.7:
           8.8.8.8:
```

my ansible script:

```
- hosts: all
  connection: local
  vars_files:
    - var.yml

  tasks:
    - name: Generate Config las routers
      template:
        src: lasinterface.j2
        dest: "{{inventory_hostname}}.config"
      when: "'LAS:routers' in group_names"
    - name: Generate Config las2 routers
      template:
        src: las2interface.j2
        dest: "{{inventory_hostname}}.config"
      when: "'LAS2:routers' in group_names"
```

getting error:

```
fatal: [1.1.1.1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "checksum": "eb27ffba3c1cf9e6768cc14a9436e0a0f94538ef", "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (ansible.legacy.copy) module: when Supported parameters include: _original_basename, attributes, backup, checksum, content, dest, directory_mode, follow, force, group, local_follow, mode, owner, remote_src, selevel, serole, setype, seuser, src, unsafe_writes, validate"}
fatal: [2.2.2.2]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "checksum": "eb27ffba3c1cf9e6768cc14a9436e0a0f94538ef", "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (ansible.legacy.copy) module: when Supported parameters include: _original_basename, attributes, backup, checksum, content, dest, directory_mode, follow, force, group, local_follow, mode, owner, remote_src, selevel, serole, setype, seuser, src, unsafe_writes, validate"}
fatal: [5.5.5.5]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "checksum": "eb27ffba3c1cf9e6768cc14a9436e0a0f94538ef", "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (ansible.legacy.copy) module: when Supported parameters include: _original_basename, attributes, backup, checksum, content, dest, directory_mode, follow, force, group, local_follow, mode, owner, remote_src, selevel, serole, setype, seuser, src, unsafe_writes, validate"}
fatal: [3.3.3.3]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "checksum": "eb27ffba3c1cf9e6768cc14a9436e0a0f94538ef", "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (ansible.legacy.copy) module: when Supported parameters include: _original_basename, attributes, backup, checksum, content, dest, directory_mode, follow, force, group, local_follow, mode, owner, remote_src, selevel, serole, setype, seuser, src, unsafe_writes, validate"}
fatal: [6.6.6.6]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "checksum": "eb27ffba3c1cf9e6768cc14a9436e0a0f94538ef", "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (ansible.legacy.copy) module: when Supported parameters include: _original_basename, attributes, backup, checksum, content, dest, directory_mode, follow, force, group, local_follow, mode, owner, remote_src, selevel, serole, setype, seuser, src, unsafe_writes, validate"}
fatal: [4.4.4.4]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "checksum": "eb27ffba3c1cf9e6768cc14a9436e0a0f94538ef", "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (ansible.legacy.copy) module: when Supported parameters include: _original_basename, attributes, backup, checksum, content, dest, directory_mode, follow, force, group, local_follow, mode, owner, remote_src, selevel, serole, setype, seuser, src, unsafe_writes, validate"}
fatal: [7.7.7.7]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "checksum": "eb27ffba3c1cf9e6768cc14a9436e0a0f94538ef", "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (ansible.legacy.copy) module: when Supported parameters include: _original_basename, attributes, backup, checksum, content, dest, directory_mode, follow, force, group, local_follow, mode, owner, remote_src, selevel, serole, setype, seuser, src, unsafe_writes, validate"}
fatal: [8.8.8.8]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "checksum": "eb27ffba3c1cf9e6768cc14a9436e0a0f94538ef", "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (ansible.legacy.copy) module: when Supported parameters include: _original_basename, attributes, backup, checksum, content, dest, directory_mode, follow, force, group, local_follow, mode, owner, remote_src, selevel, serole, setype, seuser, src, unsafe_writes, validate"}
```

How can i generate configs on specific groups also i have sub group routers/switches in both LAS and LAS2. how can i differentiate and generate configs

Comment: Wow, how old is your copy of ansible that it does not honor `when:`?

Comment: @mdaniel i am running v2.10.3 , when i use *When: "'routers' in group_names"* it works but generating configs for both routers groups in LAS and LAS2. but i need to generate configs for a specific host group as each host group has different interface.j2 template configs

Comment: Error message is talking about 'copy' module but in the code you show there is only 'template', did you show only an extract? From the message, looks like the indentation of the 'when' is wrong: it's considered as a parameter of the 'copy' module instead of being at the same level of indentation.